# How to create regex for inline ordered list?

Tags: python, regex, django

I have a form field, that most contain only inline ordered list:

```
1. This item may be contain characters, symbols or numbers. 2. And this item also...
```

The following code not working for user input validation (users can input only inline ordered list):

```
definiton_re = re.compile(r'^(?:\d\.\s(?:.+?))+$')
validate_definiton = RegexValidator(definiton_re, _("Enter a valid 'definition' in format: 1. meaning #1, 2. meaning #2...etc"), 'invalid')
```

P.S.: Here i'm using [RegexValidator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/validators/#regexvalidator) class from Django framework to validate form field value.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? What result do you want? Also, what is a string and what isn't? What's your input?

Comment: Using capture groups: `"\d. ([^\d]+)"g` [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bQ6wK7/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Nice solution from OP.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25351543/3622940) To push it further, let's do some regex optimization / golfing.

```
(?<!\S)\d{1,2}\.\s((?:(?!,\s\d{1,2}\.),?[^,]*)+)
```

Here's what's new:

- `(?:^|\s)` Matches with backtracking between the alternation. Here we use `(?<!\S)` instead, to assert that we're not in front of a non-whitespace character.
- `\d{1,2}\.\s` doesn't have to be within a non-capturing group.
- `(.+?)(?=(?:, \d{1,2}\.)|$)` is too bulky. We change this bit to:

  - `(` *Capturing group*
  - `(?:`
  - `(?!` Negative lookahead: Assert that our position is **NOT**:
  - `,\s\d{1,2}\.` A comma, whitespace character, then a list index.
  - `)`
  - `,?[^,]*` Here's the interesting optimization:
  - - We match a comma if there is one. Because we knew from our lookahead assertion that this position does not start a new list index. Therefore, we can safely assume that the remaining bit of the non-comma sequences (if there are any) are not related to the next element, hence we roll over them with the `*` quantifier, and there's no backtracking.
  - - This is a significant improvement over `(.+?)`.
  - `)+` Keep repeating the group until the negative lookahead assertion fails.
  - `)`

You can use that in place of the regex in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25351543/3622940), and here's a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/uK5eW3/2)!

---

Though, at first glance, this problem is better solved with `re.split()` while parsing:

```
input = '1. List item #1, 2. List item 2, 3. List item #3.';
lines = re.split('(?:^|, )\d{1,2}\. ', input);
 # Gives ['', 'List item #1', 'List item 2', 'List item #3.']
if lines[0] == '':
  lines = lines[1:];
 # Throws away the first empty element from splitting.
print lines;
```

Here is an [online code demo](http://ideone.com/TLC4yC).

Unfortunately, for the validation you would have to follow the regex matching approach, just compile the regex upstairs:

```
regex = re.compile(r'(?<!\S)\d{1,2}\.\s((?:(?!,\s\d{1,2}\.),?[^,]*)+)')
```

Comment: @SultanAlotaibi I see what you mean now, I designed the regex based on the test cases in the question, sorry. See my updated answer, which accounts for the actual list structure.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. It's working not bad.

```
input = '1. List item #1, 2. List item 2, 3. List item #3.'
regex = re.compile(r'(?:^|\s)(?:\d{1,2}\.\s)(.+?)(?=(?:, \d{1,2}\.)|$)')
# Parsing.
regex.findall(input) # Result: ['List item #1', 'List item 2', 'List item #3.']
# Validation.
validate_input = RegexValidator(regex, _("Input must be in format: 1. any thing..., 2. any thing...etc"), 'invalid')
validate_input(input) # No errors.
```